# NoSuchMethodException thrown when using reflection api

Tags: java, exception, reflection

I am using reflection api to invoke a method from an instance of a class. everything is ok and I followed many tutorials and official oracle docs step by step but it throws `NoSuchMethodException`. here is my code:

```
// Part of the main class
    Class[] argTypes = new Class[2];
    argTypes[0] = HttpServletRequest.getClass();
    argTypes[1] = HttpServletResponse.getClass();

    Object[] args = new Object[2];
    args[0] = request;
    args[1] = response;

    try {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName("x.xx.xxx.Default");
        Object object = cls.newInstance();
        Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("index", argTypes);
        method.invoke(object, args);
    } catch (Exception exception) { // for simplicity of the question, I replaced all exception types with Exception
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

// End of the main class
    // class x.xx.xxx.Default

    public class Default {
        public void index(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            try {
                PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
                writer.println("Welcome");
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                System.err.println(exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the description of `exception` which I gave when the exception happens

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: x.xx.xxx.Default.index(org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade, org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade)
```

Comment: Can you show the object you are trying to invoke?

Comment: @Devolus it's already there, look closer ;)

Comment: Are you sure HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse are imported correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to pass the static class and not the class at runtime.

```
Class[] argTypes = new Class[2];
argTypes[0] = HttpServletRequest.class;
argTypes[1] = HttpServletResponse.class;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the following code :

```
Class[] argTypes = new Class[2];
argTypes[0] = HttpServletRequest.getClass();
argTypes[1] = HttpServletResponse.getClass();
```

`HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` are variables, thus `getClass()` call is subject to polymorphism.

You want to write :

```
Class[] argTypes = new Class[2];
argTypes[0] = HttpServletRequest.class;
argTypes[1] = HttpServletResponse.class;
```

Comment: Thank you too from your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to invoke a method of the clas "x.xx.xxx.Default" (is that a valid class name?) on a on object of type 'Object'.

I would try this:

```
YourClassType object = (YourClassType) cls.newInstance();
```

Or something like that. i cant do a good lookup right now, but i am positive that you are trying to invoke a method from a certain type on a object of type 'Object', which doesnt know that particular method.